# displying dynamic html contents in controller on JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have an OutputStream objects which contains (HTML format) data. I need to show only this data on jsp. I am using spring framework.

How to achieve this?

I have tried PrintWriter object's print method. But it doesn't work. Is there any mistake in my following code?

```
OutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ftp.retrieveFile(remote, output); //output stream obj is generated from fetching html file from ftp server. 
PrintWriter objPrintWriter = response.getWriter();
objPrintWriter.println(output.toString());
```

Can i have a dynamic view created using current Response object, for which there is not any jsp present in application and which simply prints contents of output stream as it is.

Answer (score 0):

OutputStream is not intended to read information, but to write. Hence logically it's impossible to have an OutputStream that "contains data".

What you're probably after is reading data from an InputStream and displaying into JSP. One way to achieve is to dump all the data into String and pass it as request attribute before dispatching to JSP

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream()));
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  sb.append(line);
}
request.setAttribute("data", sb.toString());
// dispatch to jsp..
```

(code may not compile / contain bug)

Disclaimer, this is not a good method if the String content is large

Comment: thank you. Since the data is fetched from ftp, it is present in output stream object. and it will be a large data...               Can i have a dynamic view created using current Response object, for which there is not any jsp present in application and which simply prints contents of output stream as it is.

Comment: You can although that is contradicting to what you said on your question title. Obtain writer from response and you can just call the `write` method for each line obtained from inputstream

Comment: What worked is as follows. 1. setting contentType("text/html") 2. no modification in outputStream object after ftp.retrieveFile(remote, output); line and 3. returning null ModelAndView

Answer (score 0):

What worked is as follows.

1. setting contentType("text/html")
2. no modification in outputStream object after ftp.retrieveFile(remote, output); line
3. returning null ModelAndView.